# learn python the hard way exercise 23

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG8qj.png)Hello. I'm a complete beginner so probably this would be a silly question for many of you but still...
I'm having problems running this code from the 23rd exercise on LPTHW on my terminal (powershell)

```
from sys import argv
script, econding, error = argv


def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)


def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)

    print(raw_bytes, "<====>", cooked_string)

languages = open("languages.txt", encoding = "utf-16")

main(languages, encoding, error)
```

This is what I get on powershell

```
python ex23.py utf-16 strict

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "ex23.py", line 22, in <module>

main(languages, encoding, error)

NameError: name 'encoding' is not defined
```

but I don't see how the module encoding is not defined.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you, that you haven't yet defined `encoding` (ie. the compiler doesn't know, what `encoding` refers to). In this case, this is because you have a typo in this line:

```py
script, econding, error = argv
```

Should be `encoding` instead of `econding`.